# How to do Actionscript trace and/or component flow log using debugger

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

An existing (though incomplete) FLEX3 project was given to us to finish (always a nightmare).

It is quite small but highly abstracted (contains well over 150 files to support only about 10 page views). I'm attempting to trace a single mouseclick event through this maze.

Is there a way to print out an actionscript trace and/or component flow using the debugger (or any other tool that anyone knows of)?

The flash.txt file appears worthless since it doesn't contain ActionScript calls and/or component flows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will print your execution graph:

```
Trace.setLevel(Trace.METHODS, Trace.LISTENER);
Trace.setListener(handleMethods);

function handleMethods(fqcn:String, lineNumber:uint, methodName:String, methodArguments:String):void
{
  trace(methodName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oof.  Yeah, always.

The Profiler might give you useful information, but you need to pay for FlexBuilder Pro to get it, if you don't already have it.  I'm not real handy with the Profiler, so I may be off base with that advice.  It would be worth checking into, though, if you are already familiar with other profiling tools.

I would probably just start looking at every point that `.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK` occurs in the code - and `.addEventListener("click"`, just in case the previous developer chose not to use the constant, for some reason.

Obviously, that could show up a lot in 150 files, but that's how I would go about it.

I would also look at any custom events that could get into the mix.  Because maybe the CLICK event is handled at some point and the handler dispatches a custom event.  And maybe the handler for that custom event dispatches another custom event.  Or dispatches a MouseEvent.CLICK event, etc.

Hope that helps.  Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/

esp.

> AS3Trace = 1|0
>
> This one is also very useful for
>   debugging It trace every single call
>   to any function that is being called
>   in the SWF at runtime! It’s like
>   expending the StackTrace to the full
>   software run time.

And many more.